# Compare items on the same index on 2 lists

Tags: python

I have 2 lists: (the actual lists are longer)

```
list1 = ['ARHEL 7 FY2017 64-bit', u'7.2', 'BRHEL 7 FY2017 64-bit', u'7.3']

list2 = [(u'RHSA-2017:2796', u'6.7'), (u'RHSA-2017:2794', u'7.2'), (u'RHSA-2017:2793', u'7.3')]
```

How can I compare the second item numbers, i.e  `6.7` ,`7.2`, `7.3` between the lists and if there is a match between the items in the 2 lists,
like we have in list1 item 4 which is `7.3`
and list2 third tuple item 2 which is also `7.3` ,

Then create a new list of tuples (like list 2 is constructed)
taking the item that comes before the match to `7.3`
which is 'BRHEL 7 FY2017 64-bit' and add it to the new tuple list

i.e

```
list 3 = [('ARHEL 7 FY2017 64-bit', u'7.2'), ('BRHEL 7 FY2017 64-bit', u'7.3')]
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service. Please show your efforts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want :

> taking the item that comes before the match
>
> One line solution :

```
print([(list1[index-1],item) for index,item in enumerate(list1) for item1 in list2 if item==item1[1]])
```

output:

```
[('ARHEL 7 FY2017 64-bit', '7.2'), ('BRHEL 7 FY2017 64-bit', '7.3')]
```

> Detailed solution:

```
list_3=[]
for index,item in enumerate(list1):
    for item1 in list2:
        if item==item1[1]:
            list_3.append((list1[index-1],item))

print(list_3)
```

output:

```
[('ARHEL 7 FY2017 64-bit', '7.2'), ('BRHEL 7 FY2017 64-bit', '7.3')]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using the following one-line solution

```
>>> list3 = [(list1[list1.index(v)-1],v) for (k,v) in filter(lambda el:el[1] in list1, list2)]
>>> list3
[('ARHEL 7 FY2017 64-bit', '7.2'), ('BRHEL 7 FY2017 64-bit', '7.3')]
```

---

In details, first you get the filtered version of `list2`, restricted so that it contains only values that `list1` also contains

```
>>> list2_filtered = filter(lambda el:el[1] in list1, list2)
```

Then you retrieve `list1`'s elements which precedes each `v` of `list2_filtered`'s values

```
>>> list3 = [(list1[list1.index(v)-1],v) for (k,v) in list2_filtered]
>>> list3
[('ARHEL 7 FY2017 64-bit', '7.2'), ('BRHEL 7 FY2017 64-bit', '7.3')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ['ARHEL 7 FY2017 64-bit', u'7.2', 'BRHEL 7 FY2017 64-bit', u'7.3']
list2 = [(u'RHSA-2017:2796', u'6.7'), (u'RHSA-2017:2794', u'7.2'), (u'RHSA-2017:2793', u'7.3')]

result = []
for n,v in list2:
    if v in list1:
        idx = list1.index(v)
        if idx != 0: result.append((list1[idx-1], v))

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[('ARHEL 7 FY2017 64-bit', '7.2'), ('BRHEL 7 FY2017 64-bit', '7.3')]
```